# this.table is undefined in angular while making responsive datatable

Tags: angular

This is my **datatable.component.ts**

```
import { Component,AfterViewInit, OnDestroy,ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    declare var $;
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import {Users} from '../user.model';
    import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { EventsService } from '../events.service';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-datatableslibrary',
      templateUrl: './datatables.component.html'
    })
    export class DatatableslibraryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild('example') table:ElementRef; 
    example:any;
      users: any[] = [];
      dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
      dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
      private eventsSub: Subscription;


      /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */

      totalUsers =0; 
      constructor(private http: HttpClient,  public eventsService: EventsService) {
      }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.example = $(this.table.nativeElement);
         this.example.DataTable();
    }
```

It is showing that this.table is Undefined.I don't Know where I am doing mistake or even that if it is the correct method for making responsive datatable or not.My static datatable is formed.Any other suggestion will be appreciated.

This is my **datatable.component.html** I want to design responsive datatable in Angular.

```
<table id="#exemple" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm row-border hover" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
  [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>PhoneNum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.phoneNum }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id="#exemple"
```

it should be

```
#example
```

just it.

please read the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide).